# How can I use awk (first field of each file) on multiple files and get the result for each input file

Tags: awk, sequence, fasta, gnu-parallel

I've tried `ls *.fasta | parallel --gnu "awk '{print $1}' > {/.}.outputfile.txt"` 
and its not producing the result I need. I have 48 files where I need to extract these fields and output them to 48 independent files.

I can run this just fine but I have to do it for each file one by one: `awk '{print $1}' BLAST_output_file.txt > ID_ BLAST_output_file.txt`

Can someone help me out here? Thanks

Comment: By seeing your profile could see you hardly select any answer as correct one, so please give your question sometime and when you have enough answers try to select 1 of them as correct one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '{if(FILENAME!=prev){close(prev)};print $1;prev=FILENAME}'  *.fasta > output_all_file
```

In case you need to have different output file(saw from your attempt):

```
awk '{if(FILENAME!=prev){close(prev)};print $1 > (FILENAME".id.blast.out.txt");prev=FILENAME}'  *.fasta
```

Comment: This works for everything I've thrown at it. Thanks again!

Comment: Actually after 10 or so files I get an error that it makes too many files open.

Comment: @user3105519, actually I had taken care of it already by closing files

Answer (score 1):

Add {}:

```
ls *.fasta | parallel --gnu "awk '{print $1}' {} > {/.}.outputfile.txt"
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work with another file I had. Essentially a table where each string is separate by 5 spaces. When I ran awk on one file it was able to grab the first column just fine. When I ran the above script on the .tab file it just recopied the file. Why would it do this when running parallel? Thanks

Comment: Does the 'awk' part work on its own (ie. without GNU Parallel)? If not, then make that work first. Also publish an MCVE. It makes it so much easier to help you.

Answer (score -1):

Just wrote a simple bash script

```
for i in *.txt; do
    awk '{print $1}' $i > $i.id.blast.out.txt
done
```

Comment: You need not to use for loop, you could read files within awk itself. See this once too https://stackoverflow.com/a/54049213/5866580